# How to simulate Proactive SIM cards?

Tags: javacard, sim-card, tls-psk

Is there any open source project to simulate Proactive SIMs?
To do polling (send POST requests) based on TLS-PSK.

Comment: Do you mean proactive SIM (i.e. SIM Toolkit) or Java Card Connected Edition (assuming the latter)? As far as I know there are not many (if any) real javacards implementing the servlet API (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9546812/5128464))...

Comment: @vlp I mean to simulate cards behavior defined in GP Remote Application Management over HTTP
Card Specification v2.2.